# Set minimum time and timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, timeout, minimum

I have loading animation which displays while the webpage is loading in the background. Once loading is complete it disappears.

What I'd like...
1. The animation to appear for a minimum of 1 second.
2. Once the 1 second minimum has expired, the animation will be naturally removed following page loading.
3. To avoid the possibility of a fault (and watching an endless animation loop), I want the animation to time out if it takes more than 5 seconds to load.

Here's what I have so far...

```
$(window).load(function()
{ 
$('#followingBallsG').hide(); 
$('#backgroundcolor').hide(); 
});
```

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no built-in jQuery features for this. You will need to write out the logic for this. Here is a simple implementation, free of race-conditions.

```
(function(){
    var didDone = false;
    function done() {
        //Prevent multiple done calls.
        if(!didDone)
        {
            didDone = true;
            //Loading completion functionality here.
            $('#followingBallsG').hide();
            $('#backgroundcolor').hide();
        }
    }
    //Variables to keep track of state.
    var loaded = false;
    var minDone = false;
    //The minimum timeout.
    setTimeout(function(){
        mindone = true;
        //If loaded, fire the done callback.
        if(loaded)
        {
            done();
        }
    }, 1000);
    //The maximum timeout.
    setTimeout(function(){
        //Max timeout fire done.
        done();
    }, 5000);
    //Bind the load listener.
    $(window).load(function(){
        loaded = true;
        //If minimum timeout done, fire the done callback.
        if(minDone)
        {
            done();
        }
    });
})();
```

I've wrapped it in a immediately invoked function expression and assumed `$(window).load` is the event you are listening for. It should be easy to adapt this to another event or to run at another time if this is not the desired effect.

Comment: Is there anyway to set the minimum timeout when they visit the root domain (www.championfreight.co.nz) and not when they return to the homepage (www.championfreight.co.nz/index)? Hope this makes sense.

Basically I'd like visitors to see the animation when they initially visit the website/homepage and not when they navigate the site and return to the homepage.

Comment: Thanks again Alexander.

Here's the end result - www.championfreight.co.nz

Comment: You could do that using HTML5 Local Storage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) or a cookie.